# How to set external clock value for STM32F1?

Tags: stm32, clock, clock-speed, stm32f10x

I creating a project with the microcontroller ***STM32F101C8t***. This microcontroller has an internal clock of ***36MHz***. My question is how to correctly set the *external clock* value, ie what crystal value should I use. I already set the external clock pins in the ***STM32CubeMX***, now it is necessary to set the correct value for the external clock.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CubeMX there is a tab dedicated to clock setup. On the left there will be a field for the HSE value. Then you either set the PLLs manually or run the clock solver.

Comment: [random picture from the web showing the tab](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fM3idlZZswQ/V_fubkxkACI/AAAAAAACgM4/ThVeXffwgI8JfH_EKRz3nAbenKabgbEJwCLcB/s1600/image7.png) you might add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> what crystal value should I use

A common value is 8 MHz, but the chip also support other crystals in the range 8 -  32 MHz (if I recall correctly). Next you must calculate [loading capacitance](https://www.foxonline.com/pdfs/xtaldesignnotes.pdf) in order to make it oscillates stably.

A complete crystal oscillator IC can be used for the sake of convenience.

Depend on what external clock source you use, you must change `HSE` accordingly.